# Delete row from its id in table using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

I want to delete spacific row after clicking button from the reference of its id,

here is my php code,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($values)) {
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr id=\"12\">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>'<img src='/Login/product_avtar/".$row['pic']."' width=\"80\" height=\"60\">'</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pdes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['qnt'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger delete_class\" id=\"".$row['pid']."\">Delete</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
```

this is ajax,

```
$(function() {
    $( ".delete_class" ).click(function(){

    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("pid");
    var info = 'pid=' + del_id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_url,
            data: info,

                 success: function(){ 
                 alert('Successfully Deleted'); 

             } 
        });
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```

and this is ajax_url,

```
if(($_POST['pid']))
{
    $id=$_POST['pid'];
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($id);

    $option   = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE * FROM product where pid = ".$id."");
}
```

Please help to find out the solution,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used the attribute pid:

```
var del_id = element.attr("pid");
```

But the attribute specified in your HTML is id, not pid.

Change this:

```
  <button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger delete_class\" id=\"".$row['pid']."\">Delete</button>
```

To this:

```
<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger delete_class\" pid=\"".$row['pid']."\">Delete</button>
```

And try debugging in your jQuery:

```
var del_id = element.attr("pid");
console.log(del_id); // On chrome, go to the Inspect Element > console tab and check if the id retrieved is correct.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply , i've changed id to pid but its still not working,

Comment: Have you tried console.log and checked if the correct value is been retrieved on button click?

Comment: yes i've tried console but it doesnt show anything , it shows network error

Comment: try inspect element on the input box and check if it's even getting an HTML like <input .... pid = "2" ... /> for an id = 2, for e.g.

Comment: You need to provide the extension of the page like url: ajax_url.php